# hashicorp vault k8s - agent container won't initialize

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, vault

I have tried to follow Hashicorp Vault's guide on injecting secrets into an application pod: https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-sidecar#inject-secrets-into-the-pod

The problem is, that I simply cannot get the vault-agent (sidecar) to initialize.

I have tried following several guides, and I always get this error when trying to start the sidecar. I am not sure why I keep getting it, because the logs doesen't show me any errors:

```
kubectl logs pod/orgchart-6f88c9f9f4-fzwcf vault-agent -n vault
```

[image: pod initializing..]

I am not quite sure what is going on. I am following the mentioned guide quite completely.

The error happens when I try to run the deployment patch, which is used to inject the secret in the application. This is the code for the patch:

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: 'internal-app'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-database-config.txt: 'internal/data/database/config'
```

The guide says the following about the deployment patch:

> The Vault Agent Injector only modifies a deployment if it contains a specific set of annotations. An existing deployment may have its definition patched to include the necessary annotations.

So, we use the patch to modify the deployment and inject the needed secret, and we apply it like this:

```
kubectl patch deployment orgchart --patch "$(cat patch-inject-secrets.yaml)"
```

As you can see here the patch hasn't been initialized for 82 min:
[image: pods]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The provided information generally appears fine. You would need to check with Kubernetes diagnostics why the `vault-agent` sidecar container is failing to initialize.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When you say Kubernetes diagnostics do you mean a tool such as Kubeeye? I have tried to use that without luck.

Comment: Check the vault agent logs like this: `kubectl logs nameofthepod  -c vault-agent-init`

Answer (score 0):

By reading logs of `vault-agent-init` container:

```bash
kubectl logs pods/orgchart-68cc76597b-vjr2k vault-agent-init
```

I was able to understand the problem:

```
2023-12-23T18:20:51.978Z [WARN] (view) vault.read(internal/data/database/config): vault.read(internal/data/database/config): Error making API request.

URL: GET http://vault.default.svc:8200/v1/internal/data/database/config
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
    * permission denied

 (retry attempt 2 after "500ms")
```

As a temporary workaround I used `*` instead of `internal/data/database/config`:

```bash
vault policy write internal-app - <<EOF
path "*" {
   capabilities = ["read"]
}
EOF
```

It's possible to port-forward Vault UI to see secrets in UI rather than typing Vault commands in terminal:

```bash
kubectl port-forward vault-0 8200:8200
```